# mysql join three tables, the same table twice

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have three tables

1) users  - has 1 foreign key, state_id that references id on states
2) user_details - has 2 foreign keys
- user_id that references id on users
-property_state_id that references id on states

3) states

How to join these 3 tables so that I have user information, user detail information and also information from states both for state_id and property_state_id?

I have written this way in laravel

```
User::where('users.id', $id)
            ->leftJoin('states', 'users.state_id', '=', 'states.id')
            ->leftJoin('user_details', 'user_details.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
            ->first();
```

Seems like I cannot join states table twice. What solution this could have?

Comment: Yes, you can, just you need to use table alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the same table multiple times in joins, but you need to provide a table alias (s1 and s2 in the sample code below):

```
User::where('users.id', $id)
        ->leftJoin('states as s1', 'users.state_id', '=', 's1.id')
        ->leftJoin('user_details', 'user_details.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->leftJoin('states as s2', 'user_details.property_state_id', '=', 's2.id')
        ->first();
```